# Serializing ISO8601 string to C# TimeSpan

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model

My project is an ASP.Net MVC project. In JavaScript, I have an ISO 8601 string, like `"PT15M"`. How do I define my model so that it gets properly serialized to a `TimeSpan` object?

Here is my Javascript:

```
var model = new TemplateMapModel();
model.DelayBy = "PT15M";
if (PerformClientSideValidation(model)) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/TemplateMap',
        data: { templateMap: model, files: files },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#modalTemplateMap').modal('toggle');
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, e) { 
            var error = xhr.responseJSON.Message;
            ShowMessageBox("Error", error);
            ToggleBusyIndicator(false);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            TEMPLATEMAPPING.grid.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried this in my model:

```
public TimeSpan DelayBy { get; set; }
```

Doing this results in a null value. I also tried this:

```
public string DelayBy { get; set; }
```

This will work, and then I can use `XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan()` to get what I want, however, I would prefer not to do it this way because it doesn't seem like the correct way, having to declare my DelayBy as a string, then convert it in my business logic. I would like to use this definition:

```
public TimeSpan DelayBy { get; set; }
```

and have MVC automatically convert it to and from a `TimeSpan` object. Any ideas?

Comment: Is rewriting `setter` not an option for you?

Comment: @AntihypeBird - I could do that, but then I have to use `string` instead of `TimeSpan`. I'm trying to stick to using just `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Can you show/explain how you are setting the value?

Comment: @AntihypeBird - I Added my Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `setter/getter`

```
private TimeSpan _delayBy; 
public TimeSpan DelayBy { 
   get { 
      return this._delayBy;
   }
   set {
      this._delayBy = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: This will not work. If I declare the `DelayBy` as a `TimeSpan`, the setter will never get hit because the MVC converter engine is not seeing a `TimeSpan` object. It is seeing a `string` object. The solution is going to be a JavaScript solution or some kind of custom converter object.

Comment: @Icemanind just wrote the code and saw what you meant. So basically you need to convert `value` to string. Try the updated code now

Comment: Oh wait, in order to make it work you need to pass `TimeSpan` object. Nevermind im dumb

Comment: Any other ideas? Somehow I need the MVC converter to say "Okay this is a TimeSpan object. I will map it to this TimeSpan property".